# i have problem creating to different user authentication for two different apps in django

Tags: django, django-models

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    },

    'db_app1': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite1',
    },
    'db_app2': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite2'
    }
}
```

i want to create two database set for app1 and app2 where they should have a different authentication database for app1 and app2

Answer (score 0):

Add a backends.py file to your respective apps. Django docs should guild you on how to define your own authentication backends.
Then include those backends in your settings.py.